# Ffmpeg on non-rooted Android?

Tags: stock-android, command-line, ffmpeg

I've set several places where I can get a ffmpeg binary for Android, but I cannot seem to run it. I use the . command to run shell scripts, but not ffmpeg. Is there any way at all I can run ffmpeg without rooting my device? (chmod-ing it is not allowed.)
I've downloaded a binary before, and attempted to run it, but I was unable to do so because it was not marked as executable. I was not allowed to chmod it and received the following error: `Unable to chmod file: operation not permitted`.

Comment: You should edit your question and describe more details about what you have tried (commands, directories, binaries) and the problems you were facing.

Comment: Use adb to move the binary into /data/local/tmp and set appropriate permissions on that file using adb and then attempt to run binary.

Comment: I received `error: permission denied`.